# change the border color of edittext

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skoJJ.png)  my question about edittext how can I change the border if we type same value of another edittext this border appears a certain time then it disappeared ** help me please here is the code that I use

```
 public void editTextWatcher(final EditText edt) {
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText("");
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
            texts.add(et1.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et2.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et3.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et4.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et5.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et6.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et7.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et8.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et9.getText().toString());

            for (String text : texts) {
                if (s.toString().equals(text)) {

                   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "vous ne pouvez utilisez ce nombre deux fois", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    edt.setText("");
                    edt.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    return;
                }
            }

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText(s.toString());
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. May be attach a screen shot.

Comment: I added a screen shot .... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can call `setBackgroundTintList()` to change the bottom border color of your EditText:

```
yourEditTextView.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_color));
```

You can also do this in the layout resource file in XML (for API > 21) by adding this line:

```
android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
```

hope this helps!!